# PHP: Remove "\u00a0" from array of strings

Tags: php

After parsing some html, we have an array similar to `["\u00a0","\u00a0", "foo", "\u00a0", "bar"]`. I want to filter out the "\u00a0" leaving us with `["foo", "bar"]`. However, when we run an equality check, we are not getting a match.

We have tried

- `$item != "\u00a0"`
- `$item != "\\u00a0"`
- `$item != ""`
- `$item != " "`
- `$item != chr(160)`

We get the same array returned without the "\u00a0" filtered out.

```
function getContent($xPath) {
    $query = "//div[@class='WordSection1']";
    $elements = $xPath->query($query);
        
    if (!is_null($elements)) {
        $content = array();
        foreach ($elements as $element){
            $nodes = $element->childNodes;
            foreach ($nodes as $node) {
                if ($node->nodeValue != "\u00a0") {
                    $content[] = $node->nodeValue;
                }
            }
        }
        return $content;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this condition:

```
if ($node->nodeValue != "\u{00a0}") {
    $content[] = $node->nodeValue;
}
```

Here's the sample script I used:

```
<?php

$words = [chr(0xC2).chr(0xA0), 'foo', chr(0xC2).chr(0xA0), 'bar'];
$output = [];

foreach ($words as $word) {
    if ($word != "\u{00a0}")
        $output[] = $word;
}

var_dump($output);
```

Comment: For future convenience: `chr(0xC2).chr(0xA0)` is equivalent to `"\xc2\xa0"`.